# tab menu not working in IE7,8

Tags: jquery, css, cross-browser

I have made tab menu, it works fine in Chrome, IE 9,10, but not work in IE 7,8.
I have no idea what i need to change my code.

Can anyone help me ?

http://fiddle.jshell.net/927rhwgv/

```
<ul class="hr_tab menu1">  
  <li class="tab1 on" data-tab="tab-1" data-trigger-class="menu1">  
     <a href="#">tab1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="tab2" data-tab="tab-2" data-trigger-class="menu2">
     <a href="#">tab2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="tab3" data-tab="tab-3" data-trigger-class="menu3">
     <a href="#">tab3</a>
  </li>
</ul>


<div id="tab-1" class="tab_content on">111</div>
<div id="tab-2" class="tab_content">22</div>
<div id="tab-3" class="tab_content">33</div>

.tab_content { display:none; }
.tab_content.on { display:inherit;}


$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul.hr_tab li').click(function(e){
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
    $('ul.hr_tab li').removeClass('on');
    $('.tab_content').removeClass('on');
    $(this).addClass('on');
    $("#"+tab_id).addClass('on');
    $('.hr_tab').removeClass('menu1 menu2 menu3');
    $('.hr_tab').addClass($(this).attr('data-trigger-class'));
    e.preventDefault();
  });
})
```

Comment: are this fix ? if not let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you havnt included it, you may want to try putting this in the HTML head:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

It should render IE as if it was the latest version ([What does <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-e))